# Silex: Отображение SQL запросов в symfony profiler

Tags: php, doctrine2, silex

Проект на Silex.

Подключаю сервисы:

```
\Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider();
\Dflydev\Silex\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider();
\Whoops\Provider\Silex\WhoopsServiceProvider();
\Silex\Provider\WebProfilerServiceProvider();
```

Консоль профайлера отображается, но не содержит количество SQL запросов и их время.
Как подключить отображение запросов?

Answer (score 1):

Что бы в профайлере отображались запросы, нужно установить пакет https://packagist.org/packages/sorien/silex-dbal-profiler .